# Cognos Installation

Tags: installation, reporting, cognos

I want to install Cognos BI 8.3 on my laptop. 
I already have the software zipfile as a whole. Only remaining things are like downloading a server (like Tomcat?), a database (and manager like Oracle DBMS 10G Express), and connecting these all to have my Cognos function.
Basically, my aims are to access Cognos Connection portal, Report Studio, Query Studio, Event Studio, Administration, and the Framework Manager. I will be downloading raw data from various free data distribution sites, model them for mock purposes, and create reports and run them.

Would you guide me how to go through these processes and get these up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Cognos ships with Tomcat. If you follow the default installation, it will include Tomcat.

As far as a database goes, for your content store, newer versions of Cognos ship with some sort of proprietary file-based database.  You can probably use MySQL for your reporting data.

Read the documentation. Most of this is spelled out pretty clearly.

Comment: Actually, Cognos ships with Derby from the Apache project (http://db.apache.org/derby/) as its built-in database.  This option is included under the "Cognos Content Database" option.

Comment: If you are installing it on your windows laptop, you can use the IIS Server provided by Microsoft. Just enable it from "Add or remove windows components" option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Cognos server and Framework Manager.

Cognos Server contains Cognos Connection portal, Report Studio, Query Studio, Event Studio, Administration.

Please refer below urls.

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ibm-bi-capabilities/entry/cognos_10_1_installation_and_configuration_steps_on_windows_xp_32_bit1?lang=en
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/infrastructure/web_servers/page599.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Install DB;
2. Create admin user for cognos and content store DB;
3. Install Cognos BI Application Server ;
4. Copy the DB drivers in cognos path;
5. Configure the cognos BI with content store and the IIS/tomcat for web access;
6. Launch the cognos in internet explorer;
7. Import sample FM packages,reports and datasources.

Answer (score 0):

To install cognos app server, you'll firstly need to create a DB for content manager which stores all your models and report specs.